# GWT Editor: ValueListBox and Validation

Tags: gwt

I use `TextBox`- and `ValueListBox`-objects as sub-editors in an editor with validation and display the errors in the

`showErrors(List<EditorError> errorList)`

method.

It works fine with the `TextBox`-objects.

The violations of the `ValueListBox`-objects are there but the errors are not mapped to the `errorList`.

Does the GWT Editor validation work with `ValueListBox`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a [ValueBoxEditorDecorator](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/ui/client/ValueBoxEditorDecorator.html) which implements the [HasEditorErros](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/editor/client/HasEditorErrors.html) interface. That's the reason why the `TextBox` shows validation errors.

The [ValueListBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ValueListBox.html) doesn't implement the `HasEditorErrors` interface interface and thus does not show any errors.
You have to create your own `ValueListBoxEditorDecorator` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13093649/356594), [here](https://gist.github.com/3425954) or [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/vW4E_fVA-LA/jwvYNuATTBwJ) for more details)